# Safari on iPhone "... too many redirects occurred" but ASP.NET app is not issuing any 301 redirects

Tags: iphone, asp.net, redirect, cookies, safari

I have an ASP.NET "desktop friendly" site (www.company.com) and a separate "mobile friendly" site (m.company.com). Both sites have redirect rules that attempt to detect if the device is a desktop or mobile and redirect the request to the appropriate site.

There is a "View Full Site" link on the mobile site. This sets a session cookie (with the value "1") for the parent domain (.company.com) and sends the user to the desktop site. When the redirect system on the desktop site detects the cookie (which it can read because the cookie belongs to the parent domain) it skips the usual rule that redirects mobile devices to the mobile site.

This is all working fine ... except for Safari on iPhone!

For this platform only, once the link has been clicked, you don't get redirected to the desktop site and all further navigation in the mobile site results in the error "Safari cannot open the page because too many redirects occurred". If you go to the iPhone's Safari settings and click Clear Cookies normality is restored but as soon as you click the "View Full Site" link the problem reoccurs.

My first thought was that the redirect system was issuing alternating 301 redirects - i.e. creating a redirect loop. However, with a debugger attached I can see that this is not happening. There is no stream of requests and redirects issued - **not a single one in fact!!** It is almost as if Safari is issuing redirect instructions to itself.

This appears to be a common problem with Safari on the iPhone [with dozens of reports on various user forums of it happening on many sites](http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone%20redirect%20loop&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Safari%20cannot%20open%20the%20page%20because%20too%20many%20redirects%20occurred%22%20iphone&oq=%22Safari%20cannot%20open%20the%20page%20because%20too%20many%20redirects%20occurred%22%20iphone&gs_l=serp.3..0.16507.17674.0.17888.6.6.0.0.0.0.46.232.6.6.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.YOll6P88Fo8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=251ddb1278bf3ace&biw=1213&bih=793). Most users report that it only happens on their iPhone and not e.g. on their iPad.

As the server does not seem to be responsible for the problem I am scratching my head for what to do! My only ideas so far are to hide the "View Full Site" link for iPhones, or to experiment with a non-cookie based redirect-bypass.

Can anyone explain the cause and/or a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into .htaccess file.

I've had a simple redirect write in .htaccess that was preventing to be loaded on Safari. As such:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Although, this is not a fix, it's a patch.